# Piecharts with different sizes according to sample size in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to create a matrix of pie charts with different sizes (pie chart diameter) according to sample size.
Basically I want to know if there is an option that, with the code I present, makes each pie chart have a different diameter according to total sales number.

Thanks in advance,

```
goptions device=gif gsfname=chart hpos=100 vpos=100 htext=2 ftext=zapfb ;

data example4 ;
INFILE DATALINES DSD DLM='#'; 
input season $ flavor $ sales ;
datalines ;
Winter # Apple # 1675
Winter # Banana Cream # 164
Winter # Blueberry # 137
Winter # Cherry # 966
Fall # Banana Cream # 209
Fall # Blueberry # 146
Fall # Cherry # 1059
Fall # French Silk # 258
Summer # Apple # 1466
Summer # Banana Cream # 209
Summer # Blueberry # 146
Summer # Cherry # 1059
Spring # Pecan # 759
Spring # Pumpkin # 1254
Spring # Rhubarb # 318
Spring # Sweet Potato # 307
;
run ; 

filename chart "C:\My Documents\Graphs\example4.gif" ;
proc gchart data=example4 ;
title "Example 4: Most Frequently Purchased Pies by Season" ;
pie flavor / sumvar=sales noheading slice=inside value=none percent=inside
fill=solid cfill=STYBR other=5 otherlabel="All Others" group=season
across=2 down=2 ;
footnote "The 'All Others' slice contains pies purchased < 5% of the time";
run ;
quit ;
```

Comment: There is no `GCHART` option for scaling each pie's radius relative to the sum(sumvar) of the across and down groups.  You can do more compute the sums for each group and use DSGI to draw the pie charts.

Comment: **ODS layouts** enable you to integrate individual charts on one page. This must enable you to format each piechart individualy. _(To do this you must master ODS Layouts, and to automate it, you must master SAS Macro.)_

Comment: @Richard thanks I will dig up on DSGI. I never worked with such a thing.

Comment: @Dirk thanks. I have some proficiency with SAS Macro so I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else has this problem, I ended up using greplay, putting the pie charts side by side and using the radius option to scale them according to my needs.